# Some Problem about Whitman's Language

Tags: walt-whitman

> O western orb sailing the heaven,
>
> Now I know what you must have meant **as a month since I walk’d**,
>
> As I walk’d in silence the transparent shadowy night,
>
> As I saw you had something to tell as you bent to me night after
>   night,
>
> As you droop’d from the sky **low down** as if to my side, (while the
>   other stars all look’d on,)
>
> As we wander’d together the solemn night, (for something I know not
>   what kept me from sleep,)
>
> As the night advanced, and I saw on the rim of the west how full you
>   were of woe,
>
> As I stood on the rising ground in the breeze in the cool transparent
>   night,
>
> As I watch’d where you pass’d and **was lost** in the netherward black of
>   the night,
>
> As my soul in its trouble dissatisfied sank, as where you sad orb,
>
> Concluded, dropt in the night, and was gone.

This is the section 8 of "When Lilacs Last in the Dooryard Bloom’d" by Walt Whitman. I have some problems:

1. What he means by **as a month since I walk’d** in second line?
2. The use of "low down" is just redundant?
3. "As I watch’d where you pass’d and was lost", if the subject is you, why he used "was"?

Answer (score 3):

1. The *since* in **as a month since I walk’d** means 'ago'. It's a usage I haven't heard since my Northumbrian grandparents died, and I think it may have been more common up there in the North, and in Scotland, than in the rest of England.

Walter Scott's novel Waverley is properly called:

> **Waverley;
>
>    Or, 'Tis Sixty Years Since.**

From *Supplement to 'Six Months in a Convent',* by Rebecca T. Read, 1835:

> I am surprised at what the Superior says in her answer, viz., “she did not know till **some months since** that Miss Reed ever had any pretensions to the name of Mary Agnes.”

2. Perhaps "low down" **is** a little redundant. It is certainly emphatic. In everyday speech perhaps we would say, *As you droop’d **right down** from the sky as if to my side.*
3. In "As I watch’d where you pass’d and was lost", the word "was" tells us that it is **he** who was lost, not the 'orb'(1). "where you pass'd" is a subordinate clause, though really the whole poem, from the first **'as'**, in line two, to the end, consists of a subordinate clause.

(1) I mistakenly said the orb was the moon. Connoisseur corrected me. It is clearly the planet Venus.

Answer (score 0):

Full moons - and every other phase of the moon - appear at intervals of approximately a monnth. So, when Whiteman walked "a month since," was the last time the moon was full,  as it is at the time of the poem. Since it is a "transparent shadowy night" the moon was full, or close enough to full to cast shadows.

Comment: By orb he means Venus, not moon. I am sure about it and all interpreters talked about it.

Comment: @Connoisseur  Thank you. I did wonder if I was right to assume he meant the moon. I think the words 'how full you were' misled me. Have you a link to such an interpretation?